# PyCharm tells me it cannot find modules although they are there

Tags: python, import, pycharm

I started a django project, it's still very basic. There are three apps in it. The app "eventmanager" builds on the app "locationmanager". So I try to import like this:

```py
from locationmanager.models import Location
```

PyCharm claims that the reference "locationmanager" cannot be resolved. However, when I run my code with the django testserver, it runs just fine. Did I do something wrong while setting up PyCharm?

EDIT: Screenshot of my project structure in PyCharm
[image: Screenshot of my project structure in PyCharm]

Comment: Could you please attach a screenshot with your project structure?

Comment: I added the screenshot.

Comment: Please try to mark `website` directory as sources root (Right Click on it - Mark As - Sources Root)

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. That resolved it. I don't think I would have ever found that out on my own. I started this project through the terminal and eventually imported it into pycharm. I assume that I oversaw an option during import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you import a django project into pycharm, you have to set the django project folder in pycharm as the Sources Root for the reference resolving to work properly.